# Is this a complete definition of "proper initial segment" in propositional logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am reading *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* by Elliott Mendelson, Sixth Edition. The first chapter of the text deals exclusively with propositional logic.

On page 13, Exercise 1.18(b), there is a brief definition of "proper initial segment":

> If an expression $\mathscr{B}$ can be written in the form $\mathscr{CD}$, where $\mathscr{C}\neq\mathscr{B}$, then $\mathscr{C}$ is called a *proper initial segment* of $\mathscr{B}$.

**Questions**:

1. Does there exist an "empty expression" in propositional logic?
2. If the answer to 1 is "yes", could not $\mathscr{C}$ be the "empty expression"?
3. If the answers to 1 and 2 are both "yes", can a proper initial segment be the empty expression?

Comment: I assume that *expressions* according to the above text are finite not-empty strings of symbols.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA At least in this edition of the text, there is no definition of "expression". Your assumption is not crazy. I'm just trying to be careful. Is your assumption standard in other treatments of propositional logic?

Comment: No. See e.g. Ebbinghaus (page 11): "We call finite sequences of symbols from an alphabet $\mathbb A$ strings or words over $\mathbb A$. By $\mathbb A^*$ we denote the set of all strings over $\mathbb A$. The length of a string $ζ ∈ \mathbb A^*$ is the
number of symbols, counting repetitions, occurring in it . The empty string is also considered to be a word over $\mathbb A$. It is denoted by $\square$, and its length is zero."

Comment: IMO the issue is: in a general theory of "expressions", the empty string is useful. Dealing only with propositional (or predicate) logic a formula with no symbols is quite useless.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Interesting, thanks! Here's Enderton in his chapter on sentential logic: "An _expression_ is a finite sequence of symbols." As the empty sequence is finite, I guess Enderton's definition, like Ebbinghaus's, accounts for the empty expression.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Actually, I just learned that Mendelson does define "expression", but only later in the text when he's axiomatizing propositional logic (and after he's used the term "expression" about 20 times). His definition is the same as Enderton's, which would seem to make his definition of "proper initial segment" problematic.

Comment: Correct; the def of *expression* at page 27 does not rule out empty strings but the def of *formula* at page 28 rules out formulas with length zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that an author does not explicitly define a term, then we have to compare the usages of the relevant cluster of terms assuming internal coherence of the text. Mendelson defines the term *statement form* on pages 3 and 4 as

[image]

By the wording of Exercise 1.18.b on page 13, he implies that not every expression is a statement form:

[image]

We realise that any well-formed or ill-formed finite-length string (Mendelson uses the term "sequence") of symbols is an expression, as his definition on page 27 attests.

It should be remarked that those terms and considerations (length of expressions, etc.) belong to our talk of the metalogical properties of propositional calculus; they are not part of the language of propositional calculus itself.

Then, let us turn to the questions:

1. Does there exist an "empty expression" in propositional logic? Strictly speaking, no. However, as for its metalogic, yes.

So, we carry on with the other questions looking from the metalogical point of view.

2. If the answer to 1 is "yes", could not $\mathscr{C}$ be the "empty expression"? $\mathscr{C}$ could be an empty expression. In general, an empty expression (a string of length $0$) is a proper initial segment of any wff. Thus follows the answer for the question 3.

To recap:

If $\mathscr{B} =\mathscr{CD}$, where $\mathscr{C}\neq\mathscr{B}$, then

$\mathscr{C}$ is called a *proper initial segment* of $\mathscr{B}$ if $\mathscr{D}$ is non-empty,

and

$\mathscr{D}$ is called a *proper terminal segment* of $\mathscr{B}$ if $\mathscr{C}$ is non-empty.